# select 2 specific row from last 8 row for different display

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a main page with recent posts (Blog).

I want the most 2 recent ones to use in a different display [html & css] and the other 6 in something different than them.
Like in this picture...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkVeM.jpg

EDIT 1

```
// Gets 2 recent posts [displayed in 2 big boxes]
    function get_important_posts() {
    global $dblink;
    mysqli_set_charset($dblink, 'utf8');
       // if () {
            $result = mysqli_query($dblink ,"SELECT * 
                                                                    FROM `posts` 
                                                                    ORDER BY `post_id` 
                                                                    DESC LIMIT 0,2") or die(mysqli_connect_error($dblink));
            $rowNumber = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
                if ($rowNumber < 1) {
                    echo  '<div class="bigbox right">
                    <a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'">
                    <div class="bigboximg"><img src="'. $row['bigthumb'] .'" width="390" alt="' . $row['title'] .'"></div></a>
                    <a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'"><div class="bigboxtitle">' . $row['title'] . '</div></a>
                    <div class="bigboxexcerpt">'. $row['excerpt'] . '</div>
                    </div>';
                    $rowNumber++;
                } else {
                    echo  '<div class="bigbox left">
                    <a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'">
                    <div class="bigboximg"><img src="'. $row['bigthumb'] .'" width="390" alt="' . $row['title'] .'"></div></a>
                    <a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'">
                    <div class="bigboxtitle">' . $row['title'] . '</div></a>
                    <div class="bigboxexcerpt">'. $row['excerpt'] . '</div></div>';
                    $rowNumber++;
                    }

            }
    }
//}

    // Gets 5 recent posts after the 2 recent posts
    function get_posts() {
    global $dblink;
    mysqli_set_charset($dblink, 'utf8');
    $result = mysqli_query($dblink ,"SELECT * 
                                                             FROM `posts` 
                                                             ORDER BY `post_id` 
                                                             DESC LIMIT 2,5") or die(mysqli_connect_error($dblink));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
            echo  '<div class="box">
            <a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'">
            <div class="boximg"><img src="'. $row['smallthumb'] .'" width="130" alt="' . $row['title'] .'"></div></a>
            <a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'">
            <div class="boxtitle">' . $row['title'] . '</div></a>
            <div class="boxexcerpt">'. $row['excerpt'] . '</div></div>';            
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($dblink ,"SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 10");
$rowNumber = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
   if($rowNumber++ < 2){
       echo "special row";
   }
   echo  '<a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'"><strong>' . $row['title'] . '</strong></a><br>'. $row['excerpt'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use a counter variable and add a special class tag for the first two.

```
    $special_rows = 2;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $class = '';
        if ($special_rows > 0)
            $class = 'special';
        echo  '<a class="' . $class . '" href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'"><strong>' . $row['title'] . '</strong></a><br>'. $row['excerpt'];
        $special_rows --;
    }
```

Or if you want different markup:

```
    $special_rows = 2;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        if ($special_rows > 0) {
            // First or second row
            echo '<a href="post.php?id=' . $row['post_id'] .'"><strong>' . $row['title'] . '</strong></a><br>'. $row['excerpt'];
        }
        else {
            echo 'All the other boring rows';
        }
        $special_rows --;
    }
```

Comment: Hampus, thanks for the quick reply..
This might help you make sense of it.. 
http://i.imgur.com/T0imWxM.jpg